# CAN Interrupt destroys data by itself STM32

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, stm32, can-bus

today I got the problem that my CAN Interrupt destroys my Data by itself:

Case:

```
  6; ; STD    ; 000007E0; 8; 03 22 11 BD 55 55 55 55  ; ."..UUUU
  7; ; STD    ; 000007E8; 8; 03 7F 22 78 55 55 55 55  ; .."xUUUU
  9; ; STD    ; 000007E8; 8; 05 62 11 BD 0E 02 55 55  ; .b....UU
```

7F 78 means that the ECU is busy and need some time. After some time (some ms) it give me the correct answer to my question.

Here is my ISR Code:

```
    void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan) {

    if (multiFrameRequest == 1) {
        memset(Rx_Data, 0, 64);
        HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &Rx_Header, Rx_Data);
        HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &Rx_Header, Rx_Data + 8);

        CAN_Received_Data = 1;


   }
   else {
    memset(Rx_Data, 0, 8);
    if (HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &Rx_Header, Rx_Data)
            == HAL_OK) {
        CAN_Received_Data = 1;

    }
}
```

This Code works perfecly with multiframe or single Frame Messages if the answer follows the question directly.

I tried to check the RxData[3] byte from the answer to 0x78 but the ISR mosly called by the recond message (the real answer) and destroy / overwrite the RxData.

How can I check for the Error Message (0x78), wait a bit and read FIFO again?

Comment: I cannot see, where you check for 0x78.

Comment: First of all, you need to protect `Rx_Data` (and possibly other variables too) from race conditions. Otherwise, all kinds of subtle but severe and intermittent race condition bugs _will_ crap up your program. Second, you simply don't call `memset` from inside an ISR. Use pointer swaps instead of doing hard copies of the data. Why do you even need to zero-out the data for? Just keep track of the used size. And third, what do those ST bloatware calls expand to? Is it sensible code? Is it safe to call from inside an ISR?

Comment: Better yet, use DMA. Surely STM32 must support it for CAN?

Comment: I have a receive Routine where I check for 0x78. Im waiting for CAN_Received_Data == 1 then use Rx_Data but in this time a new Interrupt is called and "destroys" my Rx_Data